# algorithm2e and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, algorithm2e

I would like to put one algorithm inside one enumerated list like in the following code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,french]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Bla, bla...

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Le crible d'Eratosthène}

    \KwData{la liste $L$ des naturels compris de $2$ à $N$.}
    \KwResult{la liste $P$ des nombres premiers compris entre $2$ et $N$.}
    \BlankLine
    \For{$i = 2$ \KwTo $N$}{
        \If{$i$ n'est pas barré dans la liste $L$}{
            Barrer dans la liste $L$ les mutltiples $ki$ où $k \geq 2$.
        }
    }
    \Return{la liste $P$ des nombres non barrés.}
\end{algorithm} 

    \item Bla, bla...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The problem I met is that I obtain the following output where the algorithm is misplaced (or too width).

[image]

If someone can give one solution with the algorithm centered regarding to the page, and not to the item content, it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `algorithm2e` uses `\hsize` in its macros, which is *not* recommended.

You can probably solve the issue by saying

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\algorithm}{\hsize=\linewidth}{}{}
```

but I can't guarantee that this has no side effects.

[image]

Alternative way, using the full line width: define an `listalgorithm` environment to be used inside lists

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{listalgorithm}
 {\par\noindent\hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}%
  \minipage{\textwidth}\algorithm[H]}
 {\endalgorithm\endminipage}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Final comment. I would avoid with all my strengths to place an algorithm inside an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition. Indeed this is for at 15 to 18 years old students, so I prefer to use this not so good formatting for algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to wrap it in an appropriately-sized `minipage` environment.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,french]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Bla, bla...

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}  % <<<<< modify here <<<<<
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Le crible d'Eratosthène}

    \KwData{la liste $L$ des naturels compris de $2$ à $N$.}
    \KwResult{la liste $P$ des nombres premiers compris entre $2$ et $N$.}
    \BlankLine
    \For{$i = 2$ \KwTo $N$}{
        \If{$i$ n'est pas barré dans la liste $L$}{
            Barrer dans la liste $L$ les mutltiples $ki$ où $k \geq 2$.
        }
    }
    \Return{la liste $P$ des nombres non barrés.}
\end{algorithm} 
\end{minipage}  % <<<<< modify here <<<<<


    \item Bla, bla...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```