# Overfull hbox when using enumerate inside algorithm environment

Tags: enumerate, algorithms, algorithm2e

When I tried to use the enumerate environment inside the algorithm environment (algorithm2e package) I got this warning message:

Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) detected at line 13

Here is a minimal working example I used to test the warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Test}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first item
        \end{enumerate}
    \label{alg:test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

P.S: I really need to get rid of this warning.

Comment: If anyone come across this question: For the reverse question (`algorithm` inside `enumerate`) refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76299/250119 .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enumerate lines inside `algorithm`, don't use a `enumerate`, but rather the `linesnumbered` option when you load [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Test}
  first item\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually don't want line numbers but rather numbers that show steps of my algorithm (that's why I used enumerate)

Comment: @MedNait: Uhmm... that's the same...

Comment: Okay, then I just have to use line numbers as step numbers and make sure to stay in the same line for each step I guess.